# How can I order objects on an isometric projection, based on coordinates and size?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, isometric

I've tried to figure it out on my own, but nothing I tried really worked completely. I'm not sure if this is a math question (since it's language-independent), but I'll ask here first.

I have a set of rectangular shapes: x, y, width, height. I want to be able to sort these objects, so that they are "behind each other" when projected isometrically.

Edit: the x and y coordinates represent the "bottom left" corner of each rectangle.

Here is an example of a failed attempt:
[image]

Here is what I'm looking for:
[image]

Here is an example of an object with: x=0, y=0, width=2, height=1
[image]

The objects can be rectangles of any size (not just those shown in my example). The angle isn't really important either, let's just say 45°.

I've tried to look into Cavalier Projection and similar topics - but information about how to actually sort these objects eluded me.

**What kind of sorting algorithm can I use to sort these objects and get the correct order?**

*Edit 1:* Using @Stef's suggestion (and changing "<" to "<=" works for most cases, but as soon as more objects are added, this starts to happen:
[image]

```
// Stef's suggestion, slightly modified
compareRectangles(r1, r2):
return ((r1.x + r1.width <= r2.x) OR (r1.y+r1.height <= r2.y))
```

I've encountered this issue previously, in my own attempts. Adding or removing other boxes, can change the result. I'm not sure if this is an issue with sort(), or if it's related to objects being too "distant" from each other (so the sorting suddenly doesn't work any longer when "long" objects cut each other).

Generally, the more "square" the objects are, the less faults appear. But I'm trying to find a solution that works even with long rectangles.

*Edit 2:* Here are the coordinates of the failing above example. Sadly, this constellation is kind of fragile... adding more boxes just causes the fault to appear in a different random place. *The total constellation seems to affect the result, not each single comparison.*

```
x, y, width, height
===================
0, 4, 4, 4
0, 8, 8, 1
4, 4, 4, 2
8, 4, 1, 7
6, 6, 1, 1
5, 6, 1, 1
4, 6, 1, 1
8, 11, 1, 1
0, 2, 9, 1
0, 1, 9, 1
0, 0, 9, 1
11, 7, 1, 1
11, 8, 1, 1
11, 9, 1, 1
11, 10, 1, 1
11, 11, 1, 1
0, 10, 1, 1
0, 11, 1, 1
1, 10, 1, 1
1, 11, 1, 1
2, 10, 1, 1
2, 11, 1, 1

0, 3, 11, 1 // long box above failing box

9, 1, 1, 1 // failing box
```

Comment: That first picture is straight out of an Escher drawing

Comment: Can you mark x and y on the drawings?

Comment: @Stef sure, just a minute, I'll edit the pictures - and yes... I've tried a few different solution, each one is it's own kind of awful :)

Comment: My comment about x and y is asking two questions really: (1) which axis is the x-axis and which axis is the y-axis; (2) which point of the rectangle corresponds to the "coordinates" of that rectangle? (could be the center, or the bottomright corner, or another corner)

Comment: @Stef I forgot that, you're right. I'll edit it in. The x,y are the "bottom left" corner coordinates; I adjusted the pictures now, I hope it's clearer. I'll add the bit about the corner in the text.

Comment: Could you please provide the coordinates of the two boxes which are not sorted correctly?

Comment: @Stef I can give you the coordinates, the problem is they don't seem to matter. The overall constellation is what breaks this, not a single comparison - so it's the "overall order" that causes this effect. I can add new elements at random, and suddenly it works, and another part fails. Still, I'll add all coordinates of the boxes above, and mark the failing pair - but keep in mind that comparing two elements works fine; it fails on the "larger scale".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two rectangles A and B, there are three possible situations:

- A must be drawn before B;
- B must be drawn before A;
- It doesn't matter which is drawn first.

The third case is important; if you try to mix it in by defaulting to one of the first two cases in your comparison function, then the comparison will not be a transitive relation. In other words, you could end up with conflicting triplets A, B, C, where A must be drawn before B, B before C, and C before A.

Classical sorting algorithms operate with the assumption that the relation is both transitive (no conflicting triplets), and total (for every pair A,B, you can say which one must be drawn first).

A sorting algorithm that doesn't require the relation to be total is called a **topological sort**, and is usually described as a sort of the vertices of a directed graph. Here the vertices are the rectangles, and there is an edge from A to B if A must be drawn before A.

Hence, build your graph, and call a topological sort function on this graph.

I think the conditions for the edges are the following. For two rectangles A and B:

- if `((A.x_max <= B.x_min) AND (B.y_max <= A.y_min)) OR ((B.x_max <= A.x_min) AND (A.y_max <= B.y_min))`, then it doesn't matter which rectangle is drawn first;
- else if `((A.x_max <= B.x_min) OR (A.y_max <= B.y_min))`, then B should be drawn before A;
- else if `((B.x_max <= A.x_min) OR (B.y_max <= A.y_min))`, then A should be drawn before B.

Note that compared to your notations, I used `x_min = x,  x_max = x+width,  y_min = y,  y_max = y + height`.

Comment: Give me a bit of time to implement it and test it - but it looks very similar to what I attempted previously. I'll give it a shot and let you know :)

Comment: So, now it gets complicated. First off, I need to use "<=", since many objects have shared borders. This is a solution I tried before - it almost works. For most constellations, it works fine... but as soon as things get more complex, there's always an error. I don't know if it has to do with my implementation (javascript.sort()), or if it's just not quite the right solution yet. It seems to be related to how many objects are compared with each other - the more there are, the larger the chance that an order doesn't fit. I don't quite know why. I'll add a picture to the question.

Comment: @Katai That's actually possible, since this relation isn't a total order.

Comment: @ziggystar Isn't it a total order? It's not a total order on the set of all possible rectangles, but I think it is a total order on any set of rectangles satisfying the assumption that rectangles don't overlap.

Comment: @Katai Hmm, I'm not so sure anymore. I also thought your solution is the same as mine. I ignored height and width and used only the root point (by silently assuming it's the lower left point of the rect). I think it's enough to compare the lower right point.

Comment: @ziggystar I'm not a mathematician, but to me it seems as if the "reduction" from multiple comparisons to "one index" creates the problem. It's hard to describe, but any algorithm I use works on small scale, but starts to falter the more objects are used; and usually, it fails between distant objects - as if the ordering didn't account for 2 dimensions. All my attempts work with very "square" shapes, for example, or if I group objects in circle or square shapes - but as soon as one object is too long or high and creates a "bridge" between groupings, things fall apart. It's very strange.

Comment: Oh; of course. The problem is not that the relation is not total. The problem is that the relation is not transitive.

Comment: If the relation was transitive but not total, then we could use **topological sort**.

Comment: So a solution is to make the relation transitive but not total, by having it return "draw A before B", "draw B before A", or "doesn't matter". Then you can use it in a topological sort.

Comment: @Stef that sounds like it's going in the right direction. So how would a topological sort like that work? But even just mentioning topological sorting already gives me some resources to check out - I didn't know the wordings for these problems, I'll read into it!

Comment: @Katai You can either write the topological sort code yourself by taking inspiration from wikipedia or from a book on graph algorithms, or you can look for an existing implementation in some library (what programming language are you using?). The implementation might require you to input your data in the form of a graph, with vertices to represent the rectangles, and edges to represent the comparisons. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Stef I'm testing things in JS, but it'll end up being used in C#. Still, you gave me the breadcrumbs I need to try the next steps. This really seems to be the proper solution, so I'll accept it once able - since it will take me a while until I can get to implement and test this. Thank you very much for your insight!